# Android displaying number over icon at runtime

Tags: android, android-widget, icons, drawable

I want to show numbers over icons in my application. These numbers will come at the runtime. As shown in the image. Please help, how i can achieve this in android.

*ICON image*

[image: ICON]

Answer (score 5):

Make a FrameLayout with your ImageView, then make another imageView with the red cicle and a TextView for the number.

Then you can make this badge very easy. just play around with the layout.
In a Framelayout every Item is over another item.

Comment: you mean the first ImageView is a background of the FrameLayout?

Comment: no, framelayout and inside two imageviews, first graphic then badge